# Spring Security: IP Address Whitelist Before Deferring to HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a single URL accessible through a servlet that I have locked down using Spring Security's DaoAuthenticationProvider. I now have the requirement that certain incoming IP addresses must be whitelisted and so are not requested to authenticate.

I can hack around this easily enough by overriding DaoAuthenticationProvider's authenticate method and bypassing the superclasses's implementation if the IP address matches a known IP address but this then only works when the sender of the request supplies a username and password (even if it's nonsense). Otherwise the provider doesn't get called.

What would be the best way to do this? Should I be using a filter to bypass the authentication procedure if a known IP address is incoming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the idiomatic Spring Security way to do it is to implement a pre-authentication filter that would populate security context with a valid `Authentication` object when client is in the whitelist. You can implement such a filter from scratch (for example, [as here](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/)) or use [`AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html) (though it seems to be  overcomplicated for your task).

Comment: Thanks, that does feel like a better way to do things. I dropped the custom DaoAuthenticationProvider, extended GenericFilterBean and added the Authentication object to the context there.

Answer (score 11):

Could you just use the [`hasIpAddress()` expression](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-access-web)? We're doing that for what appears to be a similar case.

```xml
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"/>
```

Comment: I don't think you can modify the IPs at runtime this way?

Comment: How could we implement this with annotations for specific mappings in a controller?