# Spring Boot secure rest by network

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I need to secure my Rest (https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/),

But I need to secure only the if the access from outside my local network, from my local network I dont need to secure,

It`s possible to do this?

tks

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to do *IP Whitelisting*. Then you can do a pre-authentication *filter* that for request coming from those IPs would pre populates the request with an Authentication object (like setting up a generic system session) as suggested by this answer: [Spring Security: IP Address Whitelist Before Deferring to HTTP Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142690/spring-security-ip-address-whitelist-before-deferring-to-http-basic-auth)